Understanding the technical characteristics of solar light
I have a lamp with a solar panel, with the following technical characteristics:

Lamp power: 300 Watt
Battery: 3.2 Volt / 30 Amper-Hour
Solar panel: 6 Volt / 18 Watt
Lumen: 120 (lm/w)


Using these data, can I compute how much time the lamp can operate at night with a fully-charged battery?
NOTE: this is not a homework question... I am just trying to understand the meaning of technical characteristics of solar body.

the solar panel is irrelevant to the question

This question belongs on the Electrical Engineering site.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Home Improvement.

Is that LED actually 300 watts?  Or is it being advertised as equivalent to a 300 watt incandescent light (so like 5000 lumen)?

TL;DR Not very long
At night, the solar charge rate is irrelevant. Lumens per watt tells you how much light your lamp can produce, which is also irrelevant.
The only things that matter are power available and the rate you use the power. While VA and Watts are not the same, they're close enough for basic calculations of this type.
Total power available = 3.2V x 30A-Hr = 96 W-Hr.
Lamp uses 300W continuously = 300W-Hr per hour.
96 / 300 = 0.32 Hr or 19 minutes. And that's assuming the battery can discharge the full amount.
A 300W lamp at 120 lumens per watt is a BIG lamp, so I'm a bit skeptical about the lamp size.
Based on the picture, the light appears similar to various 300W actual, 2000W incandescent equivalent lights available from Amazon, with anywhere from 36,000 to 45,000 lumens. 300W x 120 lumens/Watt = 36,000 lumens, so that matches.
Which implies that if this is being sold as a package of 300W LED light + 96 Watt-Hr battery + 18 Watt solar cell that the combination is wildly mismatched. 18 Watt solar + 96 Watt-Hr battery is not unreasonable - that would charge in around 6 hours or so, assuming full solar power is available. But solar and battery way undersized for a 300W light.

I understand that the solar panel data "6 Volt / 18 Watt" are not relevant for the light time at night. So what are they relevant for - do they determine the rate that the battery is charged at day?

Yes, they determine the charge rate. But I'm sceptical about the lamp size. All lamps these days are LED, and 300W LED is simply ridiculous.

@vidarlo yes, it is very strange, because the seller says it should operate for 12-24 hours in darkness. According to the calculation in the answer, 12 hours means that the lamp is only 8 Watt.

If it's eBay or similar chinesium shop, chances are every spec is multiplied by at least ten. A good indicator is price; a LiIon (3.2V hints at lithium) 30Ah pack consists of 9 18650 cells, or similar - which should cost at least 50$. A 300W LED is not cheap and requires cooling fans... if your light was below 100-200$ you've been scammed.

Note that in these days of LED lighting, the question of bulb wattage has become unnecessarily confused. Many manufacturers describe LED illumination by the incandescent bulb it is approximately equivalent to, and that's especially likely if you are looking at marketing information. So that may mean "the light of a 300 watt bulb" even before marketing exaggeration. LEDs typically take 1/6th the energy to produce the same light as the incandescent, so the battery would last (very roughly) six times as long as it would if those were real Watts. That's still only gets us to 2 hours, though.

Maybe they have a lower intensity setting? A 300W incandescent bulb (equivalent) is more light than you need in most circumstances; you can light a smallish room adequately with a single 100W bulb. If they have a low power setting which reduces the light to this level, and are using that for their estimation, that gets us to 6 hours, which at least in midsummer approximates "all night". See if you can get a copy of the user clues to determine if this is the case. If not, they are fudging it somewhere else.

Actual available energy may be well below the 3.2V*30A-hr, depending on the battery type. Lithium should be 90% of that, lead-acid more like 50%.

@vidarlo is there a way to directly compute the actual wattage of the bulb?

Not compute, but measure. Or infer based on physical characteristics. Do you have a picture?

@vidarlo yes, I added a picture to the question

I have an idea. A standard 300-Watt lamp, in a 220 Volt system, consumes ~1.36 Ampere. So maybe the producer measured the current and found it to be 1.36 A, and estimated the wattage based on that. 1.36 A, with a 30 A*H battery, gives 22 hours. Indeed, my lamp works all night (at least 10 hours).

When batteries are listed as AH, that is based on the nominal voltage of the battery, which is typically 12V (but sometimes more on small cell phone batteries or larger in some cases) and not generally anything over 48V.
